# Archery Probability question

Tags: probability

**This** is an archery ***probability*** question...What is the methodology to solve this??

***[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fokAQ.png***

Comment: Since  you are new i want to let you know that it is preferred that you spend the time to write down your question instead of posting a link to it.

Comment: You can gauge the effectiveness of using the word "question" and a tag term like "probability" in the title from the entirely uninformative titles of the questions in the "Related" section to the right.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate of a question that has the same structure, just different probabilities. In case you have any trouble applying this to your case with different probabilities, you can ask a new question focussing specifically on where you're not sure how to apply the answer to your case.